# Smooth CSS3 transitions on iphone 4 android 4.1

Tags: android, jquery, ios, css

I build this [demo](http://kendallarneaud.me/swipedemo/) for both mobile and desktop with effects driven by CSS3 transitions. However I find that the transitions aren't as smooth as I want it to be on mobile. Its weird because I've had no problem on other sites. Can someone give me some advice on how I can achieve a more smoother animations?

Answer (score 1):

I know that on iOS the hardware acceleration isn't turned on by default but will turn on if you add a CSS 3D transform to an object on the page.  Even if you use `translate3d(0,0,0)`.

Comment: Thanks, but i have `* {
  zoom:1;   transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
            -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-user-select:none;user-select:none;-ms-touch-action:none;
 }
`

which is a 3D transformation on all objects...or did I over do it?

Comment: That should do it.  Try changing it to use something other than 0.  Maybe they've updated it to only kick on when it's actually needed.